# Windows update automatic classes

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

For Windows 7 SP1, Microsoft issues three classes of updates: *critical*, *recommended*, and *optional*.

When clients have Windows Update set to perform automatic updates, which classes of updates will they automatically receive?  Or does Windows Update not make that determination by update class?

Answer (score 1):

Default is critical updates on Win 7 SP1 and 2008 Server